# how to select a tree node span tag value in python selenium webdriver?

Tags: html, selenium-webdriver

> I am trying to select a search list tree value which is located inside a span tag. I am not able to locate its value to get this clicked.

I am sharing the HTML code as well as the picture of the focused area.
[image: Here]

> Here I am searching users value and trying to click the option available from suggestion.
> below is html code

```html
<ul class="x-tree-root-ct x-tree-lines" id="ext-gen10"><div class="x-tree-root-node"><li class="x-tree-node" style="display: none;"><div ext:tree-node-id="categories\/Accounts &amp; Contacts" class="x-tree-node-el x-unselectable folder x-tree-node-collapsed" unselectable="on"><span class="x-tree-node-indent"></span><img alt="" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAID/AMDAwAAAACH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw==" class="x-tree-ec-icon x-tree-elbow-plus"><img alt="" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAID/AMDAwAAAACH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw==" class="x-tree-node-icon" unselectable="on"><a hidefocus="on" class="x-tree-node-anchor" href="#" tabindex="1"><span unselectable="on">Accounts &amp; Contacts</span></a></div><ul class="x-tree-node-ct" style="display:none;"></ul></li><li class="x-tree-node" style="display: none;"><div ext:tree-node-id="categories\/Opportunities" class="x-tree-node-el x-unselectable folder x-tree-node-collapsed" unselectable="on"><span class="x-tree-node-indent"></span><img alt="" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAID/AMDAwAAAACH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw==" class="x-tree-ec-icon x-tree-elbow-plus"><img alt="" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAID/AMDAwAAAACH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw==" class="x-tree-node-icon" unselectable="on"><a hidefocus="on" class="x-tree-node-anchor" href="#" tabindex="1"><span unselectable="on">Opportunities</span></a></div><ul class="x-tree-node-ct" style="display:none;"></ul></li><li class="x-tree-node" style="display: none;"><div ext:tree-node-id="categories\/Customer Support Reports" class="x-tree-node-el x-unselectable folder x-tree-node-collapsed" unselectable="on"><span class="x-tree-node-indent"></span><img alt="" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAID/AMDAwAAAACH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw==" class="x-tree-ec-icon x-tree-elbow-plus"><img alt="" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAID/AMDAwAAAACH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw==" class="x-tree-node-icon" unselectable="on"><a hidefocus="on" class="x-tree-node-anchor" href="#" tabindex="1"><span unselectable="on">Customer Support Reports</span></a></div><ul class="x-tree-node-ct" style="display:none;"></ul></li><li class="x-tree-node" style="display: none;"><div ext:tree-node-id="categories\/Suspects" class="x-tree-node-el x-unselectable folder x-tree-node-collapsed" unselectable="on"><span class="x-tree-node-indent"></span><img alt="" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAID/AMDAwAAAACH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw==" class="x-tree-ec-icon x-tree-elbow-plus"><img alt="" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAID/AMDAwAAAACH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw==" class="x-tree-node-icon" unselectable="on"><a hidefocus="on" class="x-tree-node-anchor" href="#" tabindex="1"><span unselectable="on">Suspects</span></a></div><ul class="x-tree-node-ct" style="display:none;"></ul></li><li class="x-tree-node" style="display: none;"><div ext:tree-node-id="categories\/Campaigns" class="x-tree-node-el x-unselectable folder x-tree-node-collapsed" unselectable="on"><span class="x-tree-node-indent"></span><img alt="" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAID/AMDAwAAAACH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw==" class="x-tree-ec-icon x-tree-elbow-plus"><img alt="" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAID/AMDAwAAAACH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw==" class="x-tree-node-icon" unselectable="on"><a hidefocus="on" class="x-tree-node-anchor" href="#" tabindex="1"><span unselectable="on">Campaigns</span></a></div><ul class="x-tree-node-ct" style="display:none;"></ul></li><li class="x-tree-node" style="display: none;"><div ext:tree-node-id="categories\/Activities" class="x-tree-node-el x-unselectable folder x-tree-node-collapsed" unselectable="on"><span class="x-tree-node-indent"></span><img alt="" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAID/AMDAwAAAACH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw==" class="x-tree-ec-icon x-tree-elbow-plus"><img alt="" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAID/AMDAwAAAACH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw==" class="x-tree-node-icon" unselectable="on"><a hidefocus="on" class="x-tree-node-anchor" href="#" tabindex="1"><span unselectable="on">Activities</span></a></div><ul class="x-tree-node-ct" style="display:none;"></ul></li><li class="x-tree-node" style="display: none;"><div ext:tree-node-id="categories\/Contracts and Orders" class="x-tree-node-el x-unselectable folder x-tree-node-collapsed" unselectable="on"><span class="x-tree-node-indent"></span><img alt="" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAID/AMDAwAAAACH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw==" class="x-tree-ec-icon x-tree-elbow-plus"><img alt="" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAID/AMDAwAAAACH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw==" class="x-tree-node-icon" unselectable="on"><a hidefocus="on" class="x-tree-node-anchor" href="#" tabindex="1"><span unselectable="on">Contracts and Orders</span></a></div><ul class="x-tree-node-ct" style="display:none;"></ul></li><li class="x-tree-node" style="display: none;"><div ext:tree-node-id="categories\/Price Books, Products and Assets" class="x-tree-node-el x-unselectable folder x-tree-node-collapsed" unselectable="on"><span class="x-tree-node-indent"></span><img alt="" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAID/AMDAwAAAACH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw==" class="x-tree-ec-icon x-tree-elbow-plus"><img alt="" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAID/AMDAwAAAACH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw==" class="x-tree-node-icon" unselectable="on"><a hidefocus="on" class="x-tree-node-anchor" href="#" tabindex="1"><span unselectable="on">Price Books, Products and Assets</span></a></div><ul class="x-tree-node-ct" style="display:none;"></ul></li><li class="x-tree-node"><div ext:tree-node-id="categories\/Administrative Reports" class="x-tree-node-el x-unselectable folder x-tree-node-expanded" unselectable="on"><span class="x-tree-node-indent"></span><img alt="" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAID/AMDAwAAAACH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw==" class="x-tree-ec-icon x-tree-elbow-minus"><img alt="" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAID/AMDAwAAAACH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw==" class="x-tree-node-icon" unselectable="on"><a hidefocus="on" class="x-tree-node-anchor" href="#" tabindex="1"><span unselectable="on">Administrative Reports</span></a></div><ul class="x-tree-node-ct" style=""><li class="x-tree-node"><div ext:tree-node-id="xnode-169" class="x-tree-node-el x-tree-node-leaf x-unselectable file x-tree-selected" unselectable="on"><span class="x-tree-node-indent"><img alt="" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAID/AMDAwAAAACH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw==" class="x-tree-elbow-line"></span><img alt="" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAID/AMDAwAAAACH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw==" class="x-tree-ec-icon x-tree-elbow"><img alt="" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAID/AMDAwAAAACH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw==" class="x-tree-node-icon" unselectable="on"><a hidefocus="on" class="x-tree-node-anchor" href="#" tabindex="1"><span unselectable="on">Users</span></a></div><ul class="x-tree-node-ct" style="display:none;"></ul></li><li class="x-tree-node"><div ext:tree-node-id="xnode-170" class="x-tree-node-el x-tree-node-leaf x-unselectable file" unselectable="on"><span class="x-tree-node-indent"><img alt="" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAID/AMDAwAAAACH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw==" class="x-tree-elbow-line"></span><img alt="" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAID/AMDAwAAAACH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw==" class="x-tree-ec-icon x-tree-elbow"><img alt="" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAID/AMDAwAAAACH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw==" class="x-tree-node-icon" unselectable="on"><a hidefocus="on" class="x-tree-node-anchor" href="#" tabindex="1"><span unselectable="on">All Users</span></a></div><ul class="x-tree-node-ct" style="display:none;"></ul></li><li class="x-tree-node"><div ext:tree-node-id="xnode-171" class="x-tree-node-el x-tree-node-leaf x-unselectable file" unselectable="on"><span class="x-tree-node-indent"><img alt="" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAID/AMDAwAAAACH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw==" class="x-tree-elbow-line"></span><img alt="" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAID/AMDAwAAAACH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw==" class="x-tree-ec-icon x-tree-elbow"><img alt="" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAID/AMDAwAAAACH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw==" class="x-tree-node-icon" unselectable="on"><a hidefocus="on" class="x-tree-node-anchor" href="#" tabindex="1"><span unselectable="on">Users &amp; Account Classifications</span></a></div><ul class="x-tree-node-ct" style="display:none;"></ul></li><li class="x-tree-node"><div ext:tree-node-id="xnode-172" class="x-tree-node-el x-tree-node-leaf x-unselectable file" unselectable="on"><span class="x-tree-node-indent"><img alt="" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAID/AMDAwAAAACH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw==" class="x-tree-elbow-line"></span><img alt="" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAID/AMDAwAAAACH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw==" class="x-tree-ec-icon x-tree-elbow"><img alt="" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAID/AMDAwAAAACH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw==" class="x-tree-node-icon" unselectable="on"><a hidefocus="on" class="x-tree-node-anchor" href="#" tabindex="1"><span unselectable="on">Users and Manager value</span></a></div><ul class="x-tree-node-ct" style="display:none;"></ul></li><li class="x-tree-node"><div ext:tree-node-id="xnode-173" class="x-tree-node-el x-tree-node-leaf x-unselectable file" unselectable="on"><span class="x-tree-node-indent"><img alt="" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAID/AMDAwAAAACH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw==" class="x-tree-elbow-line"></span><img alt="" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAID/AMDAwAAAACH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw==" class="x-tree-ec-icon x-tree-elbow"><img alt="" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAID/AMDAwAAAACH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw==" class="x-tree-node-icon" unselectable="on"><a hidefocus="on" class="x-tree-node-anchor" href="#" tabindex="1"><span unselectable="on">Users</span></a></div><ul class="x-tree-node-ct" style="display:none;"></ul></li><li class="x-tree-node"><div ext:tree-node-id="xnode-174" class="x-tree-node-el x-tree-node-leaf x-unselectable file" unselectable="on"><span class="x-tree-node-indent"><img alt="" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAID/AMDAwAAAACH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw==" class="x-tree-elbow-line"></span><img alt="" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAID/AMDAwAAAACH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw==" class="x-tree-ec-icon x-tree-elbow-end"><img alt="" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAID/AMDAwAAAACH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw==" class="x-tree-node-icon" unselectable="on"><a hidefocus="on" class="x-tree-node-anchor" href="#" tabindex="1"><span unselectable="on">Users and Login History</span></a></div><ul class="x-tree-node-ct" style="display:none;"></ul></li></ul></li><li class="x-tree-node" style="display: none;"><div ext:tree-node-id="categories\/File and Content Reports" class="x-tree-node-el x-unselectable folder x-tree-node-collapsed" unselectable="on"><span class="x-tree-node-indent"></span><img alt="" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAID/AMDAwAAAACH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw==" class="x-tree-ec-icon x-tree-elbow-plus"><img alt="" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAID/AMDAwAAAACH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw==" class="x-tree-node-icon" unselectable="on"><a hidefocus="on" class="x-tree-node-anchor" href="#" tabindex="1"><span unselectable="on">File and Content Reports</span></a></div><ul class="x-tree-node-ct" style="display:none;"></ul></li><li class="x-tree-node"><div ext:tree-node-id="categories\/Other Reports" class="x-tree-node-el x-unselectable folder x-tree-node-expanded" unselectable="on"><span class="x-tree-node-indent"></span><img alt="" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAID/AMDAwAAAACH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw==" class="x-tree-ec-icon x-tree-elbow-end-minus"><img alt="" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAID/AMDAwAAAACH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw==" class="x-tree-node-icon" unselectable="on"><a hidefocus="on" class="x-tree-node-anchor" href="#" tabindex="1"><span unselectable="on">Other Reports</span></a></div><ul class="x-tree-node-ct" style=""><li class="x-tree-node"><div ext:tree-node-id="xnode-175" class="x-tree-node-el x-tree-node-leaf x-unselectable file" unselectable="on"><span class="x-tree-node-indent"><img alt="" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAID/AMDAwAAAACH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw==" class="x-tree-icon"></span><img alt="" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAID/AMDAwAAAACH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw==" class="x-tree-ec-icon x-tree-elbow"><img alt="" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAID/AMDAwAAAACH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw==" class="x-tree-node-icon" unselectable="on"><a hidefocus="on" class="x-tree-node-anchor" href="#" tabindex="1"><span unselectable="on">Users with Followers</span></a></div><ul class="x-tree-node-ct" style="display:none;"></ul></li><li class="x-tree-node"><div ext:tree-node-id="xnode-176" class="x-tree-node-el x-tree-node-leaf x-unselectable file" unselectable="on"><span class="x-tree-node-indent"><img alt="" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAID/AMDAwAAAACH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw==" class="x-tree-icon"></span><img alt="" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAID/AMDAwAAAACH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw==" class="x-tree-ec-icon x-tree-elbow"><img alt="" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAID/AMDAwAAAACH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw==" class="x-tree-node-icon" unselectable="on"><a hidefocus="on" class="x-tree-node-anchor" href="#" tabindex="1"><span unselectable="on">Users with Reports</span></a></div><ul class="x-tree-node-ct" style="display:none;"></ul></li><li class="x-tree-node"><div ext:tree-node-id="xnode-177" class="x-tree-node-el x-tree-node-leaf x-unselectable file" unselectable="on"><span class="x-tree-node-indent"><img alt="" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAID/AMDAwAAAACH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw==" class="x-tree-icon"></span><img alt="" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAID/AMDAwAAAACH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw==" class="x-tree-ec-icon x-tree-elbow-end"><img alt="" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAID/AMDAwAAAACH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw==" class="x-tree-node-icon" unselectable="on"><a hidefocus="on" class="x-tree-node-anchor" href="#" tabindex="1"><span unselectable="on">Users_Active</span></a></div><ul class="x-tree-node-ct" style="display:none;"></ul></li></ul></li></div></ul>
```

Kindly suggest how can I select using tabindex or any other possible way?
Here is the short block of code sharing, where I have defined variable to USERFIELD by taking class name but no luck

```
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

#search the Users from dropdown and click button
USERFIELD=(By.CLASS_NAME, "x-tree-ec-icon x-tree-elbow")
WebDriverWait(browser, 5).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable(QUICKFINDSEARCH)).send_keys("Users")
WebDriverWait(browser, 5).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable(USERFIELD)).click()
```

Comment: Can you post the complete html source of the search results? I think you should be able to select the value using xpath or indexes.

Comment: `x-tree-ec-icon x-tree-elbow` is not a valid class name! Keep in mind that in HTML the class attribute is a **space separated list** of class names.

Comment: @Sureshmani I have edited the html code , hope this is in elaborated way.

Comment: @SiKing Kindly suggest how should I locate as I had tried all possible way myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`x-tree-ec-icon x-tree-elbow` is not a valid class, as in HTML markup the [class attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/class) is a space-separated **list** of classes.

Your options are one of:

- `USERFIELD=(By.CLASS_NAME, "x-tree-ec-icon")`
- `USERFIELD=(By.CLASS_NAME, "x-tree-elbow")`
- `USERFIELD=(By.XPATH, "//*[contains(@class, 'x-tree-ec-icon x-tree-elbow')]")`

The first two options select your element by valid class. The last option uses the value of class as a string, and as such is quite slow, which probably makes it the least favourable option.

It is not clear from the HTML you posted if any of these will select the correct element. It is highly likely that multiple elements in your DOM will have, for example, the `x-tree-ec-icon` class. In this case, Selenium will pick the first one it encounters, which may or may not be the one you are interested in.

Comment: Thank you, I got this concept still click operation to first encounter is not getting performed. I have used  below code after class path defining : WebDriverWait(browser, 5).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable(USERFIELD)).click()